# Hiding QMdiArea's title bar

Tags: qt, qt5, qmdiarea

MainWindow can easily hide the title bar use :

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```

But when doing with QMdiArea, like:

```
ui->mdiArea->setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(child);
child->showMaximized();
```

Things could not work. I also try this:

```
child->setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```

and this:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowTitleHint);
```

It still showes[image]

So How can I do?

BTW: if can't make this, can I disable the 3 buttons on the left or overload these buttons event.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
child->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

Here is an example creating a sub window that is a QLineEdit. The sub window does not have a title bar:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonAddSubWindow_clicked(){
  QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit(QString("Test"), this);
  QMdiSubWindow *sub = ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(edit);
  sub->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
  edit->show();
}
```

Comment: I've noticed that if you set other flags, or set cascade or things like that may reset this flag.

Comment: You mean it really works for QMdiArea and I failed because I set other flags? I didn't set other flags.

Comment: Please see @troyane's solution, which uses `|` to combine window features (rather than your current code, which blindly overwrites them).  Often, to be safe, people will do `setWindowsFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::FramelessWindowHint)` so that you're always setting against the current flags and not overwriting.

Answer (score 1):

@Klathzazt solution worked for me as he described. Also you can use

```
auto w = new QWidget();
auto sub_w = area_.addSubWindow(w, 
             Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::Tool | Qt::WindowTitleHint);
sub_w->show();`<br>to create windows that have only title bar(no buttons).
```